# Coalesce C# .NET 4 and 6

Tags: c#, .net

This code produces different results in .NET Framework 4.7.2 and .NET 6

```
public static void Main()
{
    decimal? angka1 = null;
    decimal angka2 = 10;
    
    decimal hasil;
    hasil = angka2 - angka1 ?? 0;
    
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World: " + hasil);
}
```

[with .NET 4](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZNUyhp)

and

[with .NET 6](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KzUvjA)

The result should be:
`Variable2 - Variable1`

If `Variable1` is NULL, then only shows `Variable2`.

Thank you.

Comment: You didn't post any code. .NET Framework 4 and .NET *Core* 6 are completely different runtimes though. If you want help post your actual code and explain the problem

Comment: I posted with .NET Fiddle site. But anyway, I'll try to type it in the question.

Comment: Prints `Hello World: 0` for me for both cases.

Comment: Both fiddles return the same result - 0

Comment: Did I make a mistake? I am sure I see the real result previously.

Comment: What do you assume is the "real" result?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I mean I compare both framework and I see the different. That's why I post. .net 4 no result, and .net 6 there's a result. but why? hhmm..

Comment: You still haven't explained what the problem is or what the different outputs were. Did you except null or 0? Subtraction has higher precedence than the null-coalescing operator, so `angka2 - angka1` will be null

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, If variable1 is null .. then the result should be only variable2. Except if variable1 is not null then the calculation should run .. which is .. `variable2 - variable1`

Comment: `If variable1 is null .. then the result should be only variable2. ` No. Null isn't  0. It's an unknown value. `variable2 - variable1` is null because one of the arguments is null. `?? 0` replaces that null with 0. What you wrote in both fiddles is equivalent to `(angka2 - angka1) ?? 0`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Thank you so much. I just need a bracket. Could you please post as the answer? So I can Vote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression  `angka2 - angka1 ?? 0` is equivalent to `(angka2 - angka1) ?? 0`. Subtraction has higher precedence than the null coalescing operator.

Since one of the subtraction operators is null, the subtraction result is null as well. That null will be replaced by 0.

The operator precedence is explained in [the Operator Precedence section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence) of the [C# operators and expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators) reference. The null coalescing operator is almost at the bottom

| Operator | Category or Name |
| --- | --- |
| ..... | ...... |
| x ?? y | Null-coalescing operator |
| c ? t : f | Conditional operator |
| x = y, x += y,..., => | Assignment and lambda declaration |